# RSPEC sign in method returns error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to sign in a user via rspec and capybara. This is the first time I've written my own tests and I'm not sure what the problem is, as if I click through my application it works fine. It seems either the problem is RSPEC is not correctly filling in the fields, or not clicking the link or button but I am not sure which or how to find out.

Here is the test (edited to add this):

```
it "logs the user in and redirects them to speakeasy home on success" do
  sign_up_as_hello_world
  page.should have_content 'INSTANT MACHINE TRANSLATION'
end
```

Here is the failure

```
  1) Sign up logs the user in and redirects them to speakeasy home on success
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content 'INSTANT MACHINE TRANSLATION'
   expected to find text "INSTANT MACHINE TRANSLATION" in "Speakeasy Technology + Humanity Sign In Invalid username or password New users start out with $5 demo credit Sign Up"
 # ./spec/features/auth_spec.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the "sign up" method in my spec helper

```
def sign_up(username)
 visit "/session/new"
 click_link "signUpLink"
 fill_in "username", with: username
 fill_in "email", with: 'email@email.com'
 fill_in "password", with: 'abcdef'
 find('input[id="submitButton"]').click
end
```

I've also tried it with this as the last line but it doesn't work either

```
click_button "Sign Up"
```

And the html for the form is here (clicking the sign up link changes the submit button's value to sign up:

```
<form class="login" action="<%= session_url %>" method="post" id="mainForm">
  <%= auth_token_input%>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user[username]" id="username"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="user[email]" id="email"/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="user[password]" id="password"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="submitButton"/>
  <div style="text-align:center">
  <p>New users start out with $5 demo credit</p>
  <a href="" class="register" id="signUpLink">Sign Up</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like the error is not in the `sign_up` but in the expectation of your test. What's in `./spec/features/auth_spec.rb:40`?

Comment: You said you tried `click_button "Sign Up"` but your view shows it should be `click_button "Sign In"`

Comment: Clicking the link "Sign Up" changes the button value to "Sign Up"

Comment: And right, the sign_up doesn't actually throw an error, but it re-renders the sign up form with an error message, when it should redirect to the home page. So as of now the test should be failing, the problem is something is not getting filled in or clicked properly.

Comment: Can you post the `Sign up logs the user in and redirects them to speakeasy home on success` test here?

Comment: It's now the first code snippet

Comment: if you read the text in your failure message, it says "Invalid username or password". is there something wrong with the username or email? If you're certain that's ok... then you need to stop *after* you click "SignUp" and make sure that you are on the actual signup page (instead of the sign in page). eg immediately after you click "SignUpLink", set an expectation on the submit button being "sign up" instead of "sign in" (if that's what differentiates your form).